# Passing javascript value to form fields fails with Internet Explorer (11)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, radio-button

Here is a piece of code (ASPX/javascript) that works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but breaks in Microsoft Internet Explorer. The radio button scripting at the bottom takes values which are submitted when a radio button is selected via the function at the top.

The variable "valuetext" just takes the contents of the "value" property of the radio button and passes it back to two form fields.

Why does the 'form1.anx_1.value' not return the radio button value?

```
{...}
        //Called when radio button selected
        function ReturnVal(qid) {

            $("#cmdSubmit").removeAttr("disabled");
            if (qid=='1') {var valuetext = form1.anx_1.value};
            if (qid=='2') {var valuetext = form1.dep_1.value};
            if (qid=='3') {var valuetext = form1.anx_2.value};
            if (qid=='4') {var valuetext = form1.dep_2.value};
            if (qid=='5') {var valuetext = form1.anx_3.value};
            if (qid=='6') {var valuetext = form1.dep_3.value};
            if (qid=='7') {var valuetext = form1.anx_4.value};
            if (qid=='8') {var valuetext = form1.dep_4.value};
            if (qid=='9') {var valuetext = form1.anx_5.value};
            if (qid=='10') {var valuetext = form1.dep_5.value};
            if (qid=='11') {var valuetext = form1.anx_6.value};
            if (qid=='12') {var valuetext = form1.dep_6.value};
            if (qid=='13') {var valuetext = form1.anx_7.value};
            if (qid=='14') {var valuetext = form1.dep_7.value};

            // --- HERE IS WHERE IT BREAKS ----
            $("#values").val(valuetext);
            $("#ItemScore").val(valuetext);
            // --- BOTH ABOVE VALUES DO NOT GET PASSED ---

            document.getElementById("enter_button").src = "images/green_button.png"
        }
    </script>

<input type="hidden" name = "ItemScore" id="ItemScore" value="" />
<table align="center" style="width:1000px; border-spacing: 60px; right: auto; left: auto; background-color: #CCCCCC;">
<tr>

<%If QID = "1" Then%>
<td style="width:180px;"><h2 style="font-family: Arial; text-align: center;"> I feel happy with life in general:</h2><br />
<div id="anx_1" style="font-size: <%=FontSize%>px">
<input type="radio" id="anx_1_1" name="anx_1" value= "3" onclick="ReturnVal(<%=qid%>)" />
<label for="anx_1_1">Mostly</label>
<input type="radio" id="anx_1_2" name="anx_1" value= "2" onclick="ReturnVal(<%=qid%>)" />
<label for="anx_1_2">Quite a bit</label>
<input type="radio" id="anx_1_3" name="anx_1" value= "1" onclick="ReturnVal(<%=qid%>)" />
<label for="anx_1_3">Only a bit</label>
<input type="radio" id="anx_1_4" name="anx_1" value= "0" onclick="ReturnVal(<%=qid%>)" />
<label for="anx_1_4">Not at all</label>
</div> 
</td>
<%End If%>

{Other form elements and 'submit' button...}
```

Answer (score 0):

This piece `$("#cmdSubmit").removeAttr("disabled");` is not crossbrowser safe, you can use `$("#cmdSubmit").prop("disabled", false);` i hope this will help

P.S
ah and you better set "disabled" `$("#cmdSubmit").prop("disabled", true);` like this!

Comment: Good idea, and thanks for the advice, kanJi. I've made this change, but unfortunately it didn't resolve the problem (the button is disabled by default, so there's no other code of this kind to fix).

Somehow MSIE just isn't passing radio button values to the form elements :(